# File reading and saving to array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have a problem with my program:

```
def generate():
    list_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Open list from",filetypes = (("WSP list files","*.list"),("All files","*.*")))
    print('List opened for generation: '+list_path)
    list = open(list_path, "r")
    print(list.readlines())
    generation1 = list.readlines()
    **print(generation1[0])
    if generation1[0] == '#DOCTYPE_LIST!2.0\n':
        print('valid doc')
    else:
       print('unvalid doc')
```

The if is not working in any case, but I see that problem happens at ** marked line. It should print the content at the "first" index of generation1 array, right? But it prints: []

And with the if: it throws an error with "Index out of range"

Comment: Don't call your variables `list`, it conflicts with the python builtin

Comment: Only `generation1[0]` is enough for printing first element of generation1 list

Comment: And as for the error "index out of range", it means that your `generation1` list is empty and you are trying to print it's first element

Comment: Maybe  `list.seek(0)` between both `readlines` but it would be highly inefficient. You should justo read once and store the result in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that you print the lines first. Afterwards the file is "at its end" there are no more lines that follow that could be read with your second `readlines()` and thats the reason why generation[0] is empty.

```
def generate():
    list_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Open list from",filetypes = (("WSP list files","*.list"),("All files","*.*")))
    print('List opened for generation: '+list_path)
    with open(list_path, "r") as file:
        allLines = file.readlines()            # read all lines into a list
        print(allLines[0])                     # you can print from that list
    generation1 = allLines[:]           # or shallow copy the list of strings
    if generation1[0] == '#DOCTYPE_LIST!2.0\n':
        print('valid doc')      # and modify generation w/o touching allLines
    else:
       print('invalid doc')
```

solves it. The `with open(filename,"r") as file:` automatically closes the file object when you leave the indentation, it is the preferred way of dealing with files: [reading-and-writing-files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 1):

Must solve the problem:

```
def generate():
    list_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Open list from",filetypes = (("WSP list files","*.list"),("All files","*.*")))
    print('List opened for generation: ' + list_path)
    with open(list_path, 'r') as fd:
        lines = fd.readlines()
    print(lines)
    print(lines[0])
    if generation1[0] == '#DOCTYPE_LIST!2.0\n':
        print('valid doc')
    else:
        print('unvalid doc')
```

Comment: I know that this is bad. I just hit the script that it would work